# Eager load HTML/erb templates in Rails for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, erb

I'm following the thread on http://minhajuddin.com/2013/04/28/angularjs-templates-and-rails-with-eager-loading for eager loading HAML templates. Seems like it's a reasonable way of ensuring Angular has all the HTML partials it needs cached on initial load to avoid unnecessary round trips to the server. My question is, how does one do the same thing with regular erb/HTML templates if we do not use HAML? On this particular line:

```
$templateCache.put("<%= File.basename(f).gsub(/\.haml$/, '')  %>", <%= Haml::Engine.new(File.read(f)).render.to_json %>);
  <% end %>
```

One would need whatever the substitute is for `Haml::Engine.new` for erb templates. Is there a solution for that offhand so I can implement the above for my non-Haml based templates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original code using HAML is:

```
<% Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('app','assets','templates', '*.haml')).each do |f| %>
  $templateCache.put("<%= File.basename(f).gsub(/\.haml$/, '')  %>", <%= Haml::Engine.new(File.read(f)).render.to_json %>);
<% end %>
```

To select all ERB templates, use

```
Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'templates', '*.erb'))
# => ['a.erb', 'b.erb', ...]
```

To get the template name from a file name, use

```
File.basename(f, '.erb')
```

To render an ERB template, use

```
ERB.new(File.read(f)).result
```

Refer to the [documentation for #result](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-i-result).

Putting everything together, we get

```
<% Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('app','assets','templates', '*.erb')).each do |f| %>
  $templateCache.put("<%= File.basename(f, '.erb')  %>", <%= ERB.new(File.read(f)).result.to_json %>);
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

For ERB templates you might use:

```
<% Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('app','assets','templates', '*.erb')).each do |f| %>
    $templateCache.put("<%= File.basename(f).gsub(/\.erb$/, '')  %>", <%= ERB.new(File.read(f)).result.to_json %>);
<% end %>
```